# Issues adding resource file to accessing-data-mongodb

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

I am trying to use this Spring Boot MonogoDB example but I wanted to change the location of the monogoDB server.

http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/

I added the following line to Application.java:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/app-config.properties")
```

Plus added `app-config.properties` to `src/resources` but I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [app-config.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Can someone please help me out...

Comment: What is 'src/resources'? Not a standard location for classpath files in maven or gradle, is all. Also you could (should) use `application.properties` for a Boot app (then you don't need the `@PropertySource`).

Comment: Can you please tell me where it should be

Comment: Normally "src/main/resources".

Comment: thanks... I just seen that